# Access loop variables inside the ngx-datatable template

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I have an array of objects, say,

```
let tableData = [{key: 'Sample 1', value: [{'Hello': 'World', 'Hi': 'Bye'}, ...]}, ...]
```

I am looping through this and generating table using ngx-datatable on tableData.value.

```
<div *ngFor = "let data of tableData; index as idx">
    <ngx-datatable class="bootstrap" [columns]="tableColumn" [rows]="data.value" [columnMode]="'force'" [rowHeight]="'auto'" [reorderable]=false>
    </ngx-datatable>
</div>
<ng-template #attribTpl let-row="row" let-value="value" let-index="rowIndex">
    <div *ngIf="<<**data.key**>>" >**--**</div>
    <a href={{row.link}}>{{row.column_name}}</a>
</ng-template>
```

I need to create certain changes inside the table depending on the outer iteration that it is currently in. As highlighted, I want certain characters to appear in the row depending on the value of **data.key**. I am not able to find ways to do that and need help! TIA! Please let me know if I have not made myself clear. Also, my tableColumn looks as below:

```
this.tableColumn = [
        {
            name: 'Hello',
            cellTemplate: this.attribTpl
        },
        {
            name: 'Hi',
            prop: 'Bye'
        }
    ];
```

Comment: I understand that I have the option to flatten my array further and achieve the purpose. But I would really like to know if it can be done in any other way.

Comment: Are you creating a datatable per item in `tableData`?

Comment: @dcg I made a mistake with my data set example. I have updated it now. "tableData.value" is an array of objects and am creating a datatable for each "data.value"